# Rails 4.2.6 metodo authenticate da erro

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou tentando utilizar o método authenticate e o rails retorna NoMethodError: undefined method `authenticate' for #.

Meu controller:
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    #include SessionsHelper

```
def login
    render 'admin/login'
end

def create
    user = User.where(:email => params[:session][:email].downcase).first

    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        #log_in user
        redirect_to :controller => 'admin', :action => 'index'
    else
        flash[:danger] = "Email ou senha inválido"
        render 'login'
    end
end
```

end

Tentei fazer também pelo console do rails e retorna o mesmo erro.
Ao tentar listar os métodos do objeto pelo console ele retorna uma lista toda desorganizada "user.methods?" 
Não consigo encontrar o meu erro.

Comment: Detalhe tenho instalado bcrypt (3.1.11)
bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5)
Pelo menos constam no gem list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método authenticate existe no módulo ActiveModel::SecurePassword e precisa estar incluido no seu model, via 'has_secure_password'.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
end
```